# Euro 2024 ticket transfer

Tags: euro

For those who are reselling/gifting Euro 2024 tickets offline--

How will the main ticket not have the original buyer's name on it?
Anyone let in during 2016/2020 using a second-hand main ticket? No ID check?

Thanks!